# Text truncation of direct element content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to truncate the text in a paragraph. Paragraph has `span` tags inside so the script which I have written is counting the text inside the paragraph (including span tag content).

And end result (rendered text) is eliminating the `span` tag (I need to apply different style for span tag text so it is mandatory to retain the span tag).

So how do I count only direct content of paragraph but not the `span` text inside it.

Here is the script  used for truncation

```
    var showChar = 50;
    var moretext = "more...";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('p').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).text();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(1, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="more"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }    
    });  
    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");  
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pinun/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can only select text node inside p tag using:

```
var contents=$(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();
```

Well the second approach is slow as it involve cloning the element, finding children and then removing them. But here is how you can do it.

```
var contents= $(this).clone()
        .children()
        .remove()
        .end()
        .text();
```

Comment: In this case end result is not showing span text at all. it is totally removed. http://jsbin.com/pinun/6/

Comment: You need to only do this while making the count and not while generating the DOM.

Comment: I need solution for generating DOM

Comment: You have asked `how do I count only direct content of paragraph but not the span text inside it.` what exactly do you want.

Comment: Oh sorry for the only question line included that. I also added `(I need to apply different style for span tag text so it is mandatory to retain the span tag)`. It would be great if you can help with this.

Comment: you can append style while building span element.